# Why Eclipse is not allowing me to select EJB Client JAR for a 2.1 EJB Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, ejb-2.x, xdoclet

My environment is Java 1.7, Eclipse Luna, WildFly 8.x, XDoclet 1.2.3, Windows 7.

I want to create a new EJB 2.1 project using XDoclet.

I went to Java EE Perspective.

Select File --> New --> EJB Project to open "New EJB Project" window.

For the "**Project name**" field, I typed "Z003_Test2xEJBOnWildfly8xEJB".

For the "**Target runtime**" field, I selected "WildFly 8.x Runtime".

For the "**EJB module version**" field, I selected "2.1".

For the "**Configuration**" field, I click on Modify button to open the "Project Facets" window. In there I make sure these options are selected:

1. EJB Module 2.1 Version
2. EJBDoclet (XDoclet) 1.2.3 Version
3. Java 1.7 Version

This is how the "Project Facets" window looks:

[image]

Click OK button to close the "Project Facets" window and focus is back on "New EJB Project" window.

Click on "Next" button.

Click on "Next" button. Thats where I was expecting to select the "EJB Client JAR" option which means a separate EJB Client JAR Project will be created.

But this option is disabled. This is how it looks:

[image]

Why this option is disabled? I dont understand.

Answer (score -1):

[url=http://www.servicingstop.co.uk/car_mot.html]car service centre[/url]
dddd

Comment: Hi, please do not post link-only answers. Make sure to elaborate what exactly should be done and why.